# Why is a subsequent query not able to find newly-inserted rows?

Tags: python, mysql, database, aws-lambda, pymysql

I'm using AWS RDS, which I'm accessing with pymysql. I have a python lambda function that inserts a row into one of my tables. I then call cursor.commit() on the pymysql cursor object. Later, my lambda invokes a second lambda; this second lambda (using a different db connection) executes a SELECT to look for the newly-added row. Unfortunately, the row is not found immediately. As a debugging step, I added code like this:

**lambda_handler.py**

```
...
uuid_values = [uuid_value] # A single-item list
things = queries.get_things(uuid_values)
# Added for debugging
if not things:
    print('For debugging: things not found.')
    time.sleep(5)
    things = queries.get_things()
    print(f'for debugging: {str(things)}')
return things
```

**queries.py**

```py
    def get_things(uuid_values):
        # Creates a string of the form 'UUID_TO_BIN(%s), UUID_TO_BIN(%s)' for use in the query below
        format_string = ','.join(['UUID_TO_BIN(%s)'] * len(uuid_values))
        tuple_of_keys = tuple([str(key) for key in uuid_values])

        with db_conn.get_cursor() as cursor:
            # Lightly simplified query
            cursor.execute( '''
                SELECT ...
                FROM table1 t1
                JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
                WHERE
                    t1.uuid_value IN ({format_string})
                    AND t2.status_id = 1
                    ''' % format_string,
                    tuple_of_keys)
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            db_conn.conn.commit()
            return results
```

This outputs

```
'For debugging: things not found.'
'\<thing list\>'
```

meaning the row is not found immediately, but is after a brief delay. I'd rather not leave this delay in when I ship to production. I'm not doing anything with transactions or isolation level. So it's very strange to me that this second query would not find the newly-inserted row. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: shall we guess what  getthing actually does

Comment: Added more info

Comment: out all in a try exept and see if you get an error

Comment: Both the initial INSERT query and the later SELECT query are inside try-except blocks. Neither throws an error. The INSERT is successful, but its new rows are not immediately readable by another client, which is what I'm trying to make happen.

Comment: have committed the cursor after the insert?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling connection.commit() after inserting

Comment: then all should be wirking, this usually happens if you work on more than one database. enable general log at your mysql server and see what querys he gets, be cautious general log gets get very bog, so see that the server doesn't get too much traffuc and disabke after you gather your data

Comment: You may need to commit the other connection as well, if its isolation level prohibits seeing data changes made after it has begun a transaction.